# Unable to have two CorePlot graphs show simultaneously

Tags: ios, core-plot

I'm having an issue having two different CorePlot graphs show up in the same view. I've set up two hosting views in my view and all the referencing outlets are connected correctly. Only one of the graphs shows up correctly. Adding a quick NSLog to the `numberForPlot` method shows that only the first graph is being populated (`graph` and `graphView`) and not the second (`trend` and `trendView`). Here's the code:

```
- (void) graphSetup {
    CPTTheme *theme = [CPTTheme themeNamed:kCPTPlainWhiteTheme];

    graph = (CPTXYGraph *)[theme newGraph]; 

    graphView.hostedGraph = graph;
    graphView.allowPinchScaling = YES;

    graph.paddingLeft = -5;
    graph.paddingTop = 0;
    graph.paddingRight = -5;
    graph.paddingBottom = -5;
    graph.fill = nil;
    graph.plotAreaFrame.fill = nil;
    int a = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < [romAveragesArray count]; i++) {
        if ([romAveragesArray objectAtIndex:i] != NULL)
            a++;
    }

    int localMax = 0;
    int localMin = 0;

    for (int a = 0; a < [romAveragesArray count]; a++) {
        if ([[romAveragesArray objectAtIndex:a] getValue] > localMax)
            localMax = [[romAveragesArray objectAtIndex:a] getValue];
        else if ([[romAveragesArray objectAtIndex:a] getValue] < localMin)
            localMin = [[romAveragesArray objectAtIndex:a] getValue];
    }

    for (int a = 0; a < [obaAveragesArray count]; a++) {
        if ([[obaAveragesArray objectAtIndex:a] getValue] > localMax)
            localMax = [[obaAveragesArray objectAtIndex:a] getValue];
        else if ([[obaAveragesArray objectAtIndex:a] getValue] < localMin)
            localMin = [[obaAveragesArray objectAtIndex:a] getValue];

    }


    CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *)graph.defaultPlotSpace;
    plotSpace.xRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromInt(0)
                                                    length:CPTDecimalFromInt(145)];
    NSLog(@"%d",a);
    plotSpace.yRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromInt(0)
                                                    length:CPTDecimalFromInt(localMax+15)];




    CPTXYAxisSet *axisSet = (CPTXYAxisSet *)graph.axisSet;

    CPTXYAxis *x = axisSet.xAxis;
    x.majorIntervalLength = CPTDecimalFromFloat(10);
    x.minorTicksPerInterval = 2;
    x.borderWidth = 0;
    x.labelExclusionRanges = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                              [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(-100) 
                                                           length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(300)], 
                              nil];;

    CPTXYAxis *y = axisSet.yAxis;
    y.majorIntervalLength = CPTDecimalFromFloat(10);
    y.minorTicksPerInterval = 1;
    y.labelExclusionRanges = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                              [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(-100) 
                                                           length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(300)], 
                              nil];





    CPTScatterPlot *dataSourceLinePlot = [[CPTScatterPlot alloc] init];
    dataSourceLinePlot.identifier = @"Obama";
    dataSourceLinePlot.dataSource = self;
    CPTMutableLineStyle *style = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
    style.lineColor = [CPTColor colorWithComponentRed:0.3215686274509804 green:0.6078431372549019 blue:1.0 alpha:1.0];
    dataSourceLinePlot.dataLineStyle = style;
    [graph addPlot:dataSourceLinePlot];


    CPTScatterPlot *dataSourceLinePlot1 = [[CPTScatterPlot alloc] init];
    dataSourceLinePlot1.identifier = @"Rom";
    dataSourceLinePlot1.dataSource = self;
    CPTMutableLineStyle *style1 = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
    style1.lineColor = [CPTColor colorWithComponentRed:0.9803921568627451 green:0.47058823529411764 blue:0.47058823529411764 alpha:1.0];
    dataSourceLinePlot1.dataLineStyle = style1;
    [graph addPlot:dataSourceLinePlot1];
     [self trendSetup];

    [self postStats];

}


- (void) trendSetup {
    CPTTheme *theme1 = [CPTTheme themeNamed:kCPTPlainWhiteTheme];

    trend = (CPTXYGraph *) [theme1 newGraph];
    trendView.allowPinchScaling = YES;
    trendView.hostedGraph = trend;

    trend.paddingLeft = -5;
    trend.paddingRight = -5;
    trend.paddingTop = 0;
    trend.paddingBottom = -5;
    trend.fill =  nil;
    trend.plotAreaFrame.fill = nil;
    int obaMax, localMax;
    for (int i = 0; i < [obaArray count]; i++)
        obaMax += [[obaArray objectAtIndex:i] getValue];

    int romMax;
    for (int i = 0; i < [romArray count]; i++)
        romMax += [[romArray objectAtIndex:i] getValue];

    if (romMax > obaMax)
        localMax = romMax;
    else
        localMax = obaMax;

    CPTXYPlotSpace *trendSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *)trend.defaultPlotSpace;
    trendSpace.xRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromInt(0) length:CPTDecimalFromInt(504)];
    trendSpace.yRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromInt(0) length:CPTDecimalFromInt(localMax)];

    CPTXYAxisSet *trendSet = (CPTXYAxisSet *)trend.axisSet;

    CPTXYAxis *trendX = trendSet.xAxis;
    trendX.majorIntervalLength = CPTDecimalFromInt(10);
    trendX.minorTicksPerInterval = 2;
    trendX.borderWidth  = 0;
    trendX.labelExclusionRanges = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(-100) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(300)], nil];;

    CPTXYAxis *trendY = trendSet.xAxis;
    trendY.majorIntervalLength = CPTDecimalFromInt(10);
    trendY.minorTicksPerInterval = 2;
    trendY.borderWidth  = 0;
    trendY.labelExclusionRanges = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(-100) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(300)], nil];;

    CPTScatterPlot *trendSourceLinePlot = [[CPTScatterPlot alloc] init];
    trendSourceLinePlot.identifier = @"Obama Trend";
    trendSourceLinePlot.dataSource = self;
    CPTMutableLineStyle *style3 = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
    style3.lineColor = [CPTColor colorWithComponentRed:0.3215686274509804 green:0.6078431372549019 blue:1.0 alpha:1.0];
    trendSourceLinePlot.dataLineStyle = style3;
    [trend addPlot:trendSourceLinePlot];


    CPTScatterPlot *trendSourceLinePlot1 = [[CPTScatterPlot alloc] init];
    trendSourceLinePlot1.identifier = @"Rom Trend";
    trendSourceLinePlot1.dataSource = self;
    CPTMutableLineStyle *style4 = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
    style4.lineColor = [CPTColor colorWithComponentRed:0.9803921568627451 green:0.47058823529411764 blue:0.47058823529411764 alpha:1.0];
    trendSourceLinePlot1.dataLineStyle = style4;
    [trend addPlot:trendSourceLinePlot1];

}
```

Comment: Are both hosting views visible?

Comment: Have you put a break point on Trend setup function?

Comment: @CStreel Yes. I think the app is getting stuck in an infinite loop in the `setContentsScale` method of CorePlot's CPTLayer class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is something I found not-so-right with your code, and I think this is the reason Eric asked you if both hosting views are visible.

You are creating two `CPTXYGraph`s one called `graph` another called `trend`. I don't know how  you set up the Views in Interface Builder, but I would NOT create two `CPTXYGraph`s. I would add `trendSourceLinePlot` & `trendSourceLinePlot1` to either `trend` or `graph`.

I think, what you need to do is to present them in the same `CPTXYGraph`. So, here is my suggestion...

1. Remove the following lines in `trentSetup`

   ```
   CPTTheme *theme1 = [CPTTheme themeNamed:kCPTPlainWhiteTheme];
   trend = (CPTXYGraph *) [theme1 newGraph];
   trendView.allowPinchScaling = YES;
   trendView.hostedGraph = trend;
   trend.paddingLeft = -5;
   trend.paddingRight = -5;
   trend.paddingTop = 0;
   trend.paddingBottom = -5;
   trend.fill =  nil;
   trend.plotAreaFrame.fill = nil;
   ```
2. Replace **ONLY** the following lines

   ```
   [trend addPlot:trendSourceLinePlot];
   [trend addPlot:trendSourceLinePlot1];
   ```

   respectively with

   ```
   [graph addPlot:trendSourceLinePlot];
   [graph addPlot:trendSourceLinePlot1];
   ```

It also should speed up the loading process.

Answer (score 0):

The graph's Y range was too long. I removed sections from the tick marks section and now it updates promptly.